# How can I make UWP apps fit in the screen size?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am developing an UWP application for an 84' Microsoft Surface Hub, and I set the sizes and positions of each element based on the size of the Hub. The problem this brings about is that I cannot view the whole app when I run it on my PC which is smaller in size. What is a good way of fixing this by making the UWP app automatically fit in the screen size, and always display in full screen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to a full-screen app then see this [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RR3QncR4OI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is obviously too broad to get a specific answer but here are a couple of quick pointers to get you in the right direction

Adaptive layout in UWP - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/design-and-ui-intro

RelativePanel - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel.aspx

Adaptive Triggers - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger.aspx

You can also check the UWP Sample apps to see how Adaptive Layout works in practice - https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples