# How to scale window according to screen resolution in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am new to Stackoverflow as well as UWP (My English is regular too). I apologize in advance for my bad writing.

I am developing a windows application in `UWP`/`C#`. My monitor size is 23' and it is set to `1920x1080` (100%) resolution.

[image: Image 1]

As seen in image 1, I have configured the application in such a way that the size of the main frame is 1920x1080, therefore, when I run the application on my computer it looks perfectly (see image 2).

[image: Image 2]

However, when I run the application on another computer with a smaller screen size (17 "), it looks like in image 3, where it can be seen that the application does not fit this size. It seems to keep the original size and mi application "does not fit on the screen".
[image: image 3]

My question is: how do I program the application so that it does not lose its shape, distribution, aspect ratio, or proportion when it is run on screens that are different in size from the computer on which it was programmed? In this way, it automatically adjusts to the resolution and scale of the screen, without losing the original proportion and distribution with which it was programmed and designed.

Thank you very much for your help and understanding.

EDIT 1: I am not looking for the content of the application to fit a change of the window, but rather to fit screens of different sizes. That is, the same content, distribution and proportion are scaled to fit on any screen size, as evidenced in image 3 that does not happen. (see Image 4)

I don't want the image 3 to happen.

[image: Image 4]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make UWP apps fit in the screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778803/how-can-i-make-uwp-apps-fit-in-the-screen-size)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it is not what I am looking for. The idea is not that the layout is adaptive as the window size changes. The idea is that the content of the application fits the size of the screen, that is, if the original design is on a 23-inch screen, when it is run on a 17-inch screen it will automatically reduce all the content by a factor scale of 17/23, without changing the content distribution or proportion.

Comment: Please avoid use fixed width height for page size. it will fill the content by default with auto size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control doing exactly what you want is called [ViewBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox?view=winrt-19041), but as people already suggested above, it would be better to design adaptive UI using triggers or at least grids.

Comment: Hi Oleg,

Thank you very much for your answer. Sure enough, this is similar to what I want; however, I don't want it to do this when I resize the application window, but rather do it when what changes is the dimension of the screen. When I change computers, the application seems to keep the original dimensions, and does not adjust to the new resolution and dimension.

Comment: Sorry, but after this comment I don't quite understand what issue you want to solve. Is it login form alignment?

Comment: When I manually resize the application window (from the edges with the mouse), the ViewBox adjusts the size of the content. However, I do not want it to do this when I change the size of the window, but to do it when I change the size of the monitor, that all the content does something similar to the ViewBox but due to resolution changes.  In image 2 it can be seen that the content fits perfectly on the monitor of the computer on which the application was programmed, but when I change computers, the content is not scaled to the new screen size (image 3).

Comment: Well, there is DisplayInformation class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation?view=winrt-19041), so you can get display size and set / bind width and height of ViewBox to that values.